# How can I use string manipulation to detect and remove two different parts of a string?

Tags: bash, text-processing, string

I'm making a script that will remove the http:// or https:// from a URL. So far I've got it to remove the http://, but I can't seem to figure out how to modify it so that it will remove either that they input. Here's the code so far:

```
domain=$1

inp="${domain//http:'//'}"

echo "$inp"
```

I'm needing code that would look something like this:

```
domain=$1

inp="${domain//http:'//'} OR ${domain//https:'//'}"

echo "$inp"
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POSIX shell script:

```
inp="${domain#http*://}"
```

Test:

```
for domain in 'https://foo.bar/baz' 'http://foo.bar/baz' ; do \
    inp="${domain#http*://}" ; \
    echo "$inp" ; \
done
```

Output:

```
foo.bar/baz
foo.bar/baz
```

Answer (score 3):

Besides running twice:

#### Using extended glob:

```
shopt -s extglob
v=${domain#http?(s)://}
printf "%s\n" "$v"
```

#### Using bash internal variable `BASH_REMATCH`:

Requiring protocol:

```
if [[ "$domain" =~ https?://(.*) ]]
then
    printf "%s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
else
    printf "Not valid input: '%s'\n" "$domain"
fi
```

Not requiring protocol:

```
[[ "$domain" =~ (https?://)?(.*) ]] && v="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
printf "%s\n" "$v"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do it twice:

```
inp="${domain//http:'//'}"
inp="${inp//https:'//'}"
```

Comment: Ah well I feel dumb and that works, thanks a ton!

Comment: @Egrodo If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.